# Change Rstudio "Find" behavior

Tags: rstudio

When typing anything on RStudio Find and Replace tab, it automatically takes me to the nearest match in the script, requiring me to scroll all the way back to where I previously was writing. Is there  way to change this behavior, so the script will just not move while I type on Find and Replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you can first select the last part of the text you are currently writing, and when activating the search option in Rstudio, you will need to tick search from selection. In that case if you write your search text it will stay in your selection area. kindly refer to the below screenshot of my Rstudio[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7veA.png)